# Tunnel secure TCP server

Tags: openvpn, openssh, stunnel

Which software can be used to protect (by password/certificate) access to tcp server (e.g. webserver)?

background: the tcp server software has no authentication and cannot be modified. the service should be provided only to authenticated users.

Example:
webserver on port 80 which is blocked by firewall

Server runs on Windows or linux

5 Client computers (Windows) should access the webserver after authentication

some program starts tcp Server on port 1234 (publicly accessible, not blocked by firewall)

incoming connections on port 1234 are redirected to port 80 ***after*** successful authentication.
Traffic should be encrypted

Which software (Mode) can be used?
stunnel , openvpn, openssh

Comment: Windows or Linux? And can you add some details about why the tcp server cannot be configured to use another port and authentication.

Comment: Another port can be used but neither authentification nor encryption can be added to the server software

Comment: According to http://software.wheelhouse.org/ssl/stunnel.shtml certificate verification can do the trick?

Comment: I don't see another solution than using a modern TCP server and forwarding URLs to your limited one and receiving and passing on the answers.

Answer (score 0):

For web server, the solution lies in creating a front-end web server and using
your server as back-end.

You may use for example Apache as the front-end web server that will pass on the URL, receive the answer and return it to the user. Nginx is another popular web server.

See for example the article
[How to configure a front-end apache server and save valuable I.P.s](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-configure-a-front-end-apache-server-and-save-valuable-i-p-s/16156).

If this is not a web server, you could also look at setting up
an authenticating proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a linux server through ssh with tunneling option:
ssh -L 1234:192.168.1.1:80 user@server